# What are some non-constant functions in the following sets? Are these sets a subspace of $Y = C^1[a,b]$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, functions

Let $Y = C^1[a,b]$. What are some non-constant functions in the following sets? Are these sets a subspace of $Y = C^1[a,b]$.

a) $D = \{ y \in Y: y'(a) = 0,\, y(b) = 1\} $

b) $D = \{y  \in Y : \displaystyle \int_a^by(x) dx = 0\}$

c) $D = \{y \in Y: y'(x) = y(x), \,x \in  (a,b)\}$

Just a reminder that $Y = C^1[a,b]$ is the set of all functions y that are continuous on $[a,b]$ and continuously differentiable in $(a,b)$ and its derivative y' has finite limiting values from the right at a  and from the left at b.

The set D in a) is not a subspace since the function c*y(b) is not in D.

The set D in b) is a subspace since it contains scalar multiples and addition

I cant think of any functions besides the obvious constant functions in the last two of these sets. Need some hints.

for a) i got $y(x) = \cos(\pi(\frac{x-b}{a-b}))$. Also $y(x)=(x-a)/(b-a)$. Any more suggestions for a)? i.e what if $b=a$?

for b) i am trying to come up with a function similar to $\sin x$ except it has period b-a, and $y(a) = 0 , y(b) = 0$

Comment: a) adapt $y(x)=(x-a)^2$ and c) take $y(x)=e^x$. For b), you need to work a little more. Try an affine function which vanishes at the midpoint of the interval.

Comment: for a) i got y(x) = cos($\pi$($\frac{x-b}{a-b}$)), thanks for c).

Comment: for b) i am trying to come up with a function similar to sinx except it has period b-a, and y(a) = 0 , y(b) = 0

Comment: Yes, that would work. But I think it is somehow easier to take $f(x)=x-\frac{a+b}{2}$.

Comment: that works too, a line that goes through (a+b)/2, thanks

Comment: is the only subspace of Y, is D in b) and c) ?

Comment: Yes. D is a nullspace of a linear operator in b and c. In a, it does not even contain $0$.

Comment: By linear operator, you mean it has defined operations of addition and real scalar multiplication?

Comment: I mean $T:y\longmapsto\int_a^b y$ is linear, i.e. $T(ay+bz)=aT(y)+bT(z)$. In particular, $D=\mbox{Ker} T$ is a linear subspace.

Comment: So if D has a linear operator, it is a linear subspace of C$^1$[a,b]?

Comment: If it is the nullspace, or the range, of a linear operator, it is automatically a linear subspace. Not if $D$ is a linear operatot, which does not make sense.

Comment: Note that your linear function does not work for a as $y'(a)=\frac{1}{b-a}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a, I think it is fair to assume $a \neq b$ so your linear function is a good one.  Your answer that it is not a subspace is correct.

For b, you are correct that it is a subspace.  To make the integral zero, you need a full period of the sine wave to be $b-a$, so you want $f(x)=\sin \frac {2\pi x}{b-a}$

For c, the solution of the equation is $y= \exp(x)+c$ What can you do with that?